# Divergent arithmetic mean of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n:=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } n \text{ is a prime number } \\
0 & \mbox{else }\end{cases}$ be a sequence on $n\in \mathbb N$.

Let's consider the arithmetic mean of $a_n$, i.e. $b_n:=\dfrac1 n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.

Does $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge?

EDIT: Unfortunately it does converge to 0.

---

Can anyone help me finding a sequence which is bounded but its arithmetic mean diverges?

Comment: It does converge to zero. To convince yourself it's possible despite there being infinitely many primes, consider instead the characteristic function (that's what it's properly called) of powers of two.

Comment: It is well-known that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sim \frac{n}{\log n}$. The limit is $0$.

Comment: See point $7$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Properties_and_examples

Comment: The prime number theorem shows that $b_n$ tends to $0$. There are asymptotically $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ prime numbers not exceeding $n$.

Comment: It is irrelevant. You won't get any effort out of that one. Maybe a taunt or two for laughs at maximum.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about a sequence which is bounded but its arithmetic mean diverges. I thought this was a example for that. Can anyone find this example?

Comment: @lemontree try $a_n = (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence is bounded,
its arithmetic mean is bounded
by the same bound.

However,
if the sequence has
increasingly long sequences
of first $a$'s and then $b$'s,
its mean will first go to
$a$ and then to $b$
alternately,
so that the mean will not converge,
although it will be bounded.

For example,
if there are
$2^{2^{2n-1}} a$'s
followed by
$2^{2^{2n}} b$'s,
for each $n$,
then
the means act as described.